# ReST: How to pass list of parameters using Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, web-services, rest, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have ReST method which takes a list of custom objects (as given below). Using the list of objects it does some calculation and returns back appropriate data.

```
@POST
@Path("/getList")     
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)    
public response getList(@BeanParam List<MyObjects> myobjectsList) {          
//Iterate over the list and return        
return Response.ok(outputList).build();     
}
```

And Myobjects class looks like this:

```
public class MyObjects {
   @QueryParam       
   private String name;
   @QueryParam       
   private int age;

   public String getName() {    
       return name;    
   }

   public int getAge() {    
       return age;    
   }
}
```

There are two questions here:

1) How would the POST URL be in this case ?

2) How do we use HttpClient to pass a list of `MyObjects` to the Rest Method ?

Thanks

Comment: Some questions: 1) Why do you name the path `/getList` when you do a `PUT`? 2) Why do you annotate members of `MyObjects` with `@QueryParam`? These are annotations for parameters of `getList`.

Comment: @LutzHorn, thanks for the first point. I wanted to write POST. I am new to ReST services. So I wasn't very sure which annotation should I write in MyObjects class. Please do suggest.

Comment: What do you want this method to do? Do you want to just get an existing list? Do you want to add an item to a list?

Comment: @LutzHorn I have updated my question. I am trying get a list of custom objects and then iterate over them, do some calculations and then again return back a list of objects.

Comment: That's not REST, it is RPC (Remote Procedure Call). If you want to build a REST interface, think about what your *Resources* are.

Comment: Basically it would be a service which would be up and running all the time. Other services would be calling this using the httpClient.